# GridBagLayout: how to fill vertically using preferred width horizontally

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have an issue trying to fill vertically a `JScrollPane` (which contains a `JTable`) inside a `JPanel`: the panel should not be filled horizontally, instead, the `JScrollPane` should take only the "necessary" space.

I'm using some code found on SO to set the table preferred width according to its content (i'm also overrding  `JTable`'s `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` method).

This is a screenshot of what i want to achieve:

[image]

The `JPanel` is wider because in my application it will be part of a `CardLayout`, so the other cards width and height will determine this panel size (in the code below i'm overriding `getPreferredSize` method for convenience, but i don't want to use it).

This result can be achieved using the below code, you only need to change this line of code:

```
Object [][] data = new Object [100][1];
```

to:

```
Object [][] data = new Object [10][1];
```

The problem is when the `JTable` has more rows, in this case the vertical scrollbar will appear, but the scroll pane will "shrink":

[image]

This is the code i'm using:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
public class TableTest
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Table Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane (new MainPanel ());
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static int MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static int MAX_WIDTH = 600;

    private JTable table;

    protected MainPanel () {
        super (new GridBagLayout ());
        Object [][] data = new Object [100][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) data [i] = new String [] {"Some data ..."};
        table = new JTable (data, new String [] {""}) {
            @Override public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize () {
                int width = 0;
                for (int column = 0; column < getColumnCount (); column ++) width += columnModel.getColumn (column).getPreferredWidth ();
                return new Dimension (Math.min (MAX_WIDTH, width), Math.min (MAX_HEIGHT, getRowHeight () * getRowCount ()));
            }
        };
        table.setAutoResizeMode (JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.setShowGrid (false);
        table.setTableHeader (null);
        resizeColumns ();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (table);
        scrollPane.setBackground (table.getBackground ());
        scrollPane.getViewport ().setBackground (table.getBackground ());
        // --- Adding components ---
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add (scrollPane, c);
    }
    @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
        return new Dimension (500, 400);
    }
    protected void resizeColumns () {
        for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount (); column ++) {
            TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel ().getColumn (column);
            int width = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount (); row ++) {
                width = Math.max (table.prepareRenderer (table.getCellRenderer (row, column), row, column).getPreferredSize ().width, width);
            }
            tableColumn.setPreferredWidth (width + table.getIntercellSpacing ().width);
        }
    }
}
```

If i set `c.fill` to `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` and `c.weightx` to any positive value, the `JScrollPane` will fill the parent panel both horizontally and vertically.

How can i let the table's preferred width to be used without manually setting the `JScrollPane` size?

**EDIT**

My code is very minimal, since i saw that my problem was not related to the number of table columns. But my real program has to deal with more columns, and a huge number of rows (a million or more in many cases).

A `JList` was my first try, since i liked the way i could use a prototype value, but it was too slow to load the data (which can also be updated at runtime), all the GUI freezed with more than 200 000 rows, also due to the fact that i'm using a custom renderer.

Also, i already tried to use a `BorderLayout`, but i really want the scrollpane height to fill my panel, i have tried different solutions, but still i can't solve it.

**EDIT2**

As @camickr suggests, i could use a BorderLayout for my panel, adding the scrollpane at BorderLayout.WEST to fill the panel vertically wihout taking all the horizontal space. This is the best solution for now, but this will cause the horizontal center alignment to be lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `BoxLayout` instead?

Comment: @crizzis Yes i tried, if i use BoxLayout the result is the same as using GridBagConstraints.BOTH: the scrollpane is filling the panel both horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (in the code below i'm overriding getPreferredSize method for convenience, but i don't want to use it

I agree. Get rid of the override.

The painting problem when you decrease the height of the frame is because the GridBagLayout will paint the component at its minimum size when there is not enough space.

So, although in general I don't like using any of the set??? methods to hardcode a size the following seems to work:

```
scrollPane.setMinimumSize(scrollPane.getPreferredSize());
```

This will keep the scrollpane width from decreasing.

If you don't like playing with hardcoded sizes you could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). This will easily allow you to center a component.

Then basic code would be:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.X_AXIS);
rl.setFill( true );
setLayout(rl);

...

add(Box.createHorizontalGlue(), new Float(1));
add(scrollPane);
add(Box.createHorizontalGlue(), new Float(1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was a bit difficult to reply in this comment field, so i edited my question.

Comment: ``Also, i already tried to use a BorderLayout, but i really want the scrollpane height to fill my panel` - that is exactly the way a BorderLayout will work - which is why I made the suggestion.

Comment: Ok, i was confused because you said "`... but the height will vary`". This is my best try at the moment, but in this way i would lose center alignment.
In a previous edit i said `maybe i could try to put the scrollpane in BorderLayout.WEST, wrapping it into a panel with a FlowLayout to align it on the center ...`, i removed it because i know that a FlowLayout will not work, do you have any better idea to align the whole scrollpane on the center?

Comment: @Ansharja, reread the question closer. Think I have a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, this solution works. I'll take a read of RelativeLayout, but for now i prefer the simpler solution. I'm wondering if it would be better to override `getMinimumSize ()` method (`public Dimension getMimimumSize () { return getPreferredSize ();}`) instead of using setter method, since the data and the table scroll pane dimension will change at runtime. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your layout problem is caused by your `GridBagConstraints` (especially [`fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#fill) and [`weightx`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx))
which prevented the `scrollPane` from using the available horizontal space.

Instead of

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.weightx = 0.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
add (scrollPane, c);
```

you should use

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;  // !!
c.weightx = 1.0;                   // !!
c.weighty = 1.0;
add (scrollPane, c);
```

Then it will look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i already said it in my question: `If i set c.fill to GridBagConstraints.BOTH and c.weightx to any positive value, the JScrollPane will fill the parent panel both horizontally and vertically.` This is not what i'm trying to achieve.